# Can I prevent Experience Manager from showing Dynamic Templates in the Layout section?

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

If I click on a component in Experience Manager and select the **Layout** tab, I see a list of component templates linked to the component schema. Unfortunately, I have a lot of system Component Templates which are not for editorial use (they are dynamic and are not allowed to be used to put components on pages), but which appear and are selectable in the **Layout** tab . If I select one, I even get an error, and then cannot switch back or do anything else until I click **Cancel Editing**:

> Invalid value for property 'ComponentPresentations'. A dynamic
>   Component Template you have selected is not allowed on a Page. Unable
>   to save item

I would not expect these CTs to appear (they would not appear when editing the page in the CME) , so is there some configuration I have missed, or is this a bug?

Comment: Your DCTs definitely don't have "allow on page using dynamic assembly" checked?

Comment: Definately - otherwise I would not get that fairly clear error message either I guess!

Comment: :P Just checking! Sounds like on for Support to me.

Comment: I have raised a ticket... will update when I hear more

Comment: Good find. Would hiding them via permissions work? I've seen requests to "configure" the CTs and/or PTs in XPM. This would make a good SDL Tridion Idea if it's expected current behavior (I'm thinking the error means it might be).

Comment: Good idea Alvin, however I want it also to 'work' for users with higher level rights - and as is, XPM gets its knickers in a right twist once the invalid template is selected.

Comment: @WillPrice - just wondering if you've an answer to this one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires hotfix CME_2013.0.0.87205. The hotfix was originally issued for 2013 GA, and didn't make it into 2013 SP1, however I have tested the hotfix on SP1 and it works.